# Finding all points where function is analytic - and finding derivative at these points

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:** Let $$ f(x,y) = \cos (x) - i \sin (y). $$ Find all the points where this complex function is analytic. Also, find the value of the derivative at these points.

**Attempt:** We have that $u(x,y) = \cos x$ and $v(x,y) = - \sin y$. The first set of the Cauchy-Riemann equations imply that \begin{align*} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = - \cos y = - \sin x = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \end{align*} Hence we must have that $$ \cos y = \sin x. $$ From the identity $ \cos (\pi/ 2 - t ) = \sin t$, I think we must have $y = \pi/ 2 - x$. The second set of the C-R equations give both zero. Now, should I just compute the derivative using the formula $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} $$ ? This would just give me $ f'(x,y) = - \sin x$.

Comment: It seems OK. But it depends how one defines analytic function, should the function has derivative in a neighborhood of the point?

Comment: We defined it as follows. Necessary condition: CR-equations are satisfied. Sufficient condition: partial derivatives are continuous functions.

Comment: I mean: for an open domain $D$, we call a function $f$ analytic if it is differentiable in $D$.

Comment: But $\{y = \pi/ 2 - x\}$ is not an open domain.